# How to force k8s to reload image when changing ConfigMap

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

I have the following yaml, that I would like to reload the image, when ever I change the configMap and apply. Do you know how to reload the image when `kubectl apply -f` :

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-configmap
data:
  index.html: |
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Testing FluxCD</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Version 2.0</h1>
      </body>
    </html>
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
  annotations:
   "version": "2"
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-nginx
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: html
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
      volumes:
      - name: html
        configMap:
          name: my-configmap
EOF
```

I have tried to look at changing the annotation, as I saw some talk about that if the imagePullPolicy is set to Always it would reload when changingn the anotation - but nothing happens.

Comment: If you _reload_ the image, that would just mean creating a whole new pod, right?

Comment: Yes, but it will when use the new settings in the ConfigMap

Answer (score 0):

I found that there is actually a TTL for ConfigMaps, then the data will updated in the mounted pods. To trigger an immediate update you can edit the pod's [annotations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#mounted-configmaps-are-updated-automatically).

Comment: just for ref, auto update configmap in mounted path : https://faun.pub/update-configmap-without-restarting-pod-56801dce3388